# PHP file_put_contents() filename contains accents

Tags: php, encoding

I want to call function file_put_contents() and everything runs correctly, except for the filename which contains accents (diacritics). It does save the file, but the filename is not encoded the right way.

What should I do? Is any special encoding required in file_put_contents()?

Comment: php + string encodings is a nightmare. but it usually uses the encoding of the php script file itself. can you check which encoding the php file has? (your IDE or Notepad++ should be able to do that)

Comment: apparently you can also use this function here to find out or set the current string encoding http://php.net/manual/de/function.mb-internal-encoding.php. i assume that it isnt utf8, thats why you get the problem. also, what OS are you using? also, what php version?

Comment: It says UTF-8 but in the console this error appears: _unable to auto detect encoding for C:\xampp\htdocs\Webcontrol\userdata\kOdeslani\1407\TĹ™Ă­dÄ›nĂ­ ĹˇroubĹŻ, using fallback encoding Western (Windows 1252)_

Comment: What I think is strange is that when I echo the filename string just before the file_puts_contents() function it displays in the right way. But the function then sets the filename to this: _TĹ™Ă­dÄ›nĂ­ ĹˇroubĹŻ_

Comment: I am using php 5.6.8. My OS is Windows 8

Comment: echo prints to your browser, and the browser uses the encoding from the http header or the html meta tag. doesn't anything and isn't strange. do these values come from the database? also please answer my other question. especially the one about the encoding of the php file (not the file you are trying to save, that doesnt matter). also use the function that i posted the link to. There are no easy answers with php encodings. the whole thing is completely f***** up in php and has been for over 10 year. just search stackoverflow for php encoding and you will see

Comment: if you use utf8 for EVERYTHING with php, usually everything works fine as a rule of thumb, anything else and you will have a bad time